# Retinal eccentricity to colour sensitivity

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

Colour perception goes out to 50 degrees but is the sensitivity to RGB. Question is it the same in the four quadrants of the retinal field? That is if the red colour sensitivity eg is 30 temporal retina 50 degree nasal retina etc. And what are the eccentric limits for each colour [frequency]in the four quadrants.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but a good reference point in the citations.

Comment: I think the PO specifically asks about the differences between quadrants here

Comment: Simon: could you clarify your question a bit? As of now it is unclear as to what you exactly wish to know. The linked answer by @anongoodnurse is indeed a very good starting point (and a very nice answer :-)